# Is there any way to add button handler to a component without regenerating function each update?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple *React **Component*** and I want to convert it to functional component, but this component receives *id* as a prop and I need to create handler for button and pass to it this *id*. But if I create function inside component it leads to regeneration and it is bad practice.

I already tried using useCallback fucntion, but it's just memoization and I think if next value will be different from previous function will regenerate.

```
// @flow
type Props = {|
  id: string,
  onClick: (id: string) => void,
|};

const Item = ({ id, onClick }: Props) => {
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    onClick(id);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <Card onClick={handleClick}>
      <CardContent />
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Compoent receives props in upper component via `map` like:

```
items.map(item => <Item id={item.id} onClick={this.handleItemClick} />)
```

Maybe some *React **Hooks*** will help, but i didn't find something useful.

Comment: Please add the full component and also how it recieves the props

Comment: `useCallback` is for creating memoized callback. If you want to memoize the value (that happens to be a callback) you could use `useMemo(() => () => onClick(id), [id])`. But in your case you need to use [`React.memo` HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

Comment: @YuryTarabanko But it works only in case if id doesn't change. In case of re-render function inside component will regenerate

Comment: @ArtemBalamutyuk Different id - another function, seems valid.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Component accepts id and pass it to onClick function, so this in one function, that accepts one parameter and it shouldn't regenerate

Comment: This would be true if you could pass those id and onClick via arguments  because "each" component has its **own** id and onClick. So you have different function for each render (or per instance if you had a stateful component). You could say put `id` in `data-id` and use `e.target.dataset` to access it. But I would recommend against this approach. Do not overthink it. Using `React.memo` should suffice unless you have like thousands of items (which is a completely different story).